# I have a problem with my Pickle Dump...can anyone figure this out?

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to save an object in my python file so that I can load it. Its a UI for a Table Top RPG, so there is only 1 class called Player. However, I'm getting an error called "Ran out of input." I have found that it is because my pickle file is empty. However, I have used to exact same code before to save succesfully...so I'm very confused. Code is below. Is my object messed up? It doesn't seem to be because the program is working fine...something is fishy.

Object

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.strength = 0
    self.strbonus = 0
    self.dex = 0
    self.dexbonus = 0
    self.con = 0
    self.conbonus = 0
    self.intel = 0
    self.intelbonus = 0
    self.wis = 0
    self.wisbonus = 0
    self.cha = 0
    self.chabonus = 0
    self.hp = 0
    self.maxhp = 0
    self.armor = 0
    self.level = 0
    self.xp = 0
    self.inventory = {"Basic Clothes": 0}
    self.physique = " "
    self.face = " "
    self.skin = " "
    self.hair = " "
    self.clothing = " "
    self.virtue = " "
    self.vice = " "
    self.speech = " "
    self.background = " "
    self.misfortune = " "
    self.alignment = " "
    self.copper = 0
    self.inventoryslots = 0
    self.currentinventory = sum(Player.inventory.values())
    self.rations = 0
```

Save code

```
if option == "9":
    with open('savefile', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(Player, f)
        print("\n Game has been saved! And so has your soul!\n")
        input("->")
        mainscreen()
```

Load code

```
if os.path.exists("savefile") == True:
    os.system('cls')
    with open("savefile", "rb") as f:
        global Player
        Player = pickle.load(f)
        print("Loaded save state...your journey continues!")
        input("->")
        mainscreen()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: Did you change the `Player` class since you last wrote the save file?

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the class `Player` but not an instance of `Player`.